# How to change project targetframework dynamically

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

We have to migrate our 500 applications from old framework to 4.5.1 framework. One option is open all application solution and change their entire project Target framework to 4.5.1 one by one. Which is time consuming process and there can be a case where our developer can miss to change target framework. When we open our solution into visual studio 2013 it ask to migrate our projects to VS 2013 compatible. I write utility with following code to do automatically upgrade project or solution file by using following command.

```
devenv.exe /upgrade <project file (.vcproj)>
devenv.exe /upgrade <solution file (.sln)>
```

But project target framework is not change, which I can expect it migrate only projects according to VS 2013. Is there any command available where I can pass TargetFramework and along with project file and it migrate it according to that?

Answer (score 0):

I use following Visual Studio Extension to migrate Target Framework :

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13

It migrate all your .Net projects to another .Net Framework Version at once.